# Cocoa-Touch: UIPickerView viewForRow is changing row orders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIPickerView. I'm customizing it's rows via it's delegate's viewForRow as follows:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    if (view) {
        return view;
    } else {
        NSString *s = [datePickerValues objectAtIndex:row];

        UILabel *l = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)] autorelease];
//        l.text = s;
        l.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ r:%ld", s, row];
        l.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
        l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        l.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        return l;
    }
}
```

When I spin it around for a bit, the rows get mixed up.
I even get the same row two or more times, and sometimes missing rows. The row count is always at 10 tho, it just seems to be calling the delegate's `viewForRow` method with a wrong `row` parameter.

I'm using the `row` paremeter to identify the rows. (as the documentation says). It has a single component, so the `component` param is always `0`, I've verified this with the debugger.

Another weird thing, according to the documentation, once I create the view for a specific row, the delegate's `view` parameter will have that view, but using the debugger I've seen that the delegate's `viewForRow` is sometimes called more than once for the same row with a `view = nil`.

Any idea why this strange behavior? I'm new to cocoa and Obj-C, am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

From the docs:
`view` - A view object that was previously used for this row, but is now hidden and cached by the picker view.

So this means that the 2nd time the delegate's `viewForRow` is called for a specific row, it will have the view returned on call 1. This makes sense since this way the delegate wouldn't have to re-create the view over and over as the user spins the control.
I've verified that in fact the `viewForRow` is called EVERY time a row is displayed, even if it was previously displayed.

What then is the use for the `view` parameter? The two answers so far don't seem to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that UIPickerView tries to **re**use your already created views for new rows for performance reasons. In this case ( `(view != nil)` ) you just return the same view you had for some previous row. 
If your view is always is a UILabel you can rewrite your code like that (sorry didn't compile it):

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    NSString *s = [datePickerValues objectAtIndex:row];

    UILabel *l = (view != nil)? view : [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)] autorelease];
    l.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ r:%ld", s, row];
    l.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    l.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    return l;
}
```

it must work ok.

Comment: yes, it does work in this case, but please read my above edit

Comment: It's just my guess now, but it easy to check. There must be some confusion of terms - the actual row you have in your picker (and data source) and the row the picker displays. So with the 2nd definition you have just 7 rows for standard picker - 5 visible and 2 for scrolling purposes. I've added NSLog messages - UIPicker creates exactly 7 views for me.
But I agree that docs appear somewhat confusing in that point.

Answer (score 2):

You must update the data in the view each time this method is called.  By not updating you are returning stale/duplicated data.

Comment: I had a similar issue -- when the view was being loaded, I was selecting a row (that was out of view). The loading for the component was showing up as the wrong indexes, but those 'incorrect' indexes were then REloaded, and I was rewriting the data, so they were never getting the correct row's data.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a very old question, but I was having the same issue with iOS7 and could not find a satisfactory answer. When I tried to tap into the 'row' parameter from the viewForRow delegate method, it would return incorrect and mixed up values.

I was able to solve this issue by doing the following,

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
...

    //Create a label
    //Set a tag for label
    //Add label to view as a subview
    //return view

 if (component == 1) {
    view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    correctRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 20)];
    [correctRowLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", row]];
    [correctRowLabel setTag:100];
    [view addSubview: correctRowLabel];
    return view;
  }
```

After the component is setup as desired, at the beginning of the viewForRow delegate method, implement the following to view the correct row values,

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UILabel* correctRow = (UILabel*)[pickerView viewWithTag:100];
    NSInteger correctRowValue = [correctRow.text integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Correct row is: %li",correctRowValue);
    UILabel* correctRowLabel = nil;

...
```

EDIT:

I wanted to add that the rowHeightForComponent must be set to default and the label must be reset at the top of viewForRow method. It isn't working perfectly but it is significantly better than before. If i learn of anything else I'll update this post.